# Nested JSON parsing pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, nested-json

I have a nested json body like below:

`{ "MainTag": { "GroupId": "10C81", "IDArray": [ "ABC-XYZ-123" ], "IDStruct": { "DSA-ASA-211": null, "BSA-ASA-211": null, "ABC-XYZ-123": [ { "BagId": "42425fsdfs", "TravelerId": "1234567", "LegCorr": [ { "DelID": "SQH", "SegID": "PQR-UVW" }, { "DelID": "GFS", "SegID": "GHS-UVW" } ] } ] } } }`

My desired output is:
[image]

Note: The **IDStruct** tag will only have value for the keys present in array tag **IDArray**.

Can someone please help me here in achieving this using PySpark.

Below is the printSchema() output:

[image]

Comment: Is "IDArray" IDs the same as the name of "IDStruct" field which you need most (which is not null)?

Comment: @ZygD : Yes...that is correct

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can do it using function `explode`.
First, I will create the structure for our data. Then create a data frame and explode all the arrays between.

```
data = { "MainTag": { "GroupId": "10C81", "IDArray": [ "ABC-XYZ-123"],` "IDStruct": { "DSA-ASA-211": "null", "BSA-ASA-211": "null", "ABC-XYZ-123": [ { "BagId": "42425fsdfs", "TravelerId": "1234567", "LegCorr": [ { "DelID": "SQH", "SegID": "PQR-UVW" }, { "DelID": "GFS", "SegID": "GHS-UVW" } ] } ] } } }
    
    from pyspark.sql.types import *
    schema_main = StructType([
        StructField('MainTag', StructType([
            StructField('GroupId', StringType()),
            StructField('IDArray', ArrayType(StringType())),
            StructField('IDStruct', StructType([
                StructField('DSA-ASA-211', StringType()),
                StructField('BSA-ASA-211', StringType()),
                StructField('ABC-XYZ-123', ArrayType(
                    StructType([
                        StructField('BagId', StringType()),
                        StructField('TravelerId', StringType()),
                        StructField('LegCorr', ArrayType(
                            StructType([
                                StructField('DelID', StringType()),
                                StructField('SegID', StringType())
                            ])
                        ))
                    ])
                ))
            ]))
        ]))
    ])
    
    df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[data], schema=schema_main)
    
    from pyspark.sql.functions import explode
    df.select("MainTag", "MainTag.GroupId", explode("MainTag.IDArray").alias("ID")) \
    .select("GroupId", "ID", explode("MainTag.IDStruct.ABC-XYZ-123").alias("ABC")) \
    .select("GroupId", "ID", "ABC.BagId", "ABC.TravelerId", explode("ABC.LegCorr").alias("Legs")) \
    .select("GroupId", "ID", "BagId", "TravelerId", "Legs.DelID", "Legs.SegID") \
    .show(truncate=False)
```

Here is the result:

```
+-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
|GroupId|ID         |BagId     |TravelerId|DelID|SegID  |
+-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
|10C81  |ABC-XYZ-123|42425fsdfs|1234567   |SQH  |PQR-UVW|
|10C81  |ABC-XYZ-123|42425fsdfs|1234567   |GFS  |GHS-UVW|
+-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks. But, the real issue is the keys in the tag 'IDStruct' are not static and will vary for each record, which is why i cannot hardcode these while defining the schema. Basically i cannot specify the 3 ids "DSA-ASA-211", "BSA-ASA-211", "ABC-XYZ-123"
as column names.

Comment: @Vaibhav you may try making the IDArray of type ArrayType(StringType()) and then translate the json later using from_json function. Something like df.withColumn("IDArray", from_json(...)), but still it may work only if you have the same schema in one dataset. If each row is different, then it may not work.

Answer (score 0):

It's convenient to use [`inline`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#inline) to expand arrays of struct. In the following code it's used 3 times.

This is your data:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import re
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [({"GroupId":"10C81","IDArray":["ABC-XYZ-123"],"IDStruct":{"DSA-ASA-211":None,"BSA-ASA-211":None,"ABC-XYZ-123":[{"BagId":"42425fsdfs","TravelerId":"1234567","LegCorr":[{"DelID":"SQH","SegID":"PQR-UVW"},{"DelID":"GFS","SegID":"GHS-UVW"}]}]}},)],
    "MainTag struct<GroupId:string, IDArray:array<string>, IDStruct:struct<`ABC-XYZ-123`:array<struct<BagId:string,LegCorr:array<struct<DelID:string,SegID:string>>,TravelerId:string>>,`DSA-ASA-211`:string,`BSA-ASA-211`:string>>")
df.printSchema()
# root
#  |-- MainTag: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- GroupId: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |-- IDArray: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
#  |    |-- IDStruct: struct (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- ABC-XYZ-123: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- BagId: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- LegCorr: array (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- DelID: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |    |    |-- SegID: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |    |    |-- TravelerId: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- DSA-ASA-211: string (nullable = true)
#  |    |    |-- BSA-ASA-211: string (nullable = true)
```

Script:

```py
df = df.selectExpr("inline(array(MainTag))")
df = df.selectExpr(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c != 'IDStruct'],
    "inline(IDStruct.`ABC-XYZ-123`)")
df = df.selectExpr(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c != 'LegCorr'],
    "inline(LegCorr)")
df = df.withColumn("IDArray", F.explode("IDArray"))

df.show()
# +-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
# |GroupId|    IDArray|     BagId|TravelerId|DelID|  SegID|
# +-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
# |  10C81|ABC-XYZ-123|42425fsdfs|   1234567|  SQH|PQR-UVW|
# |  10C81|ABC-XYZ-123|42425fsdfs|   1234567|  GFS|GHS-UVW|
# +-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
```

---

If you don't want to hard-code "ABC-XYZ-123", one of possible ways is to change the schema for "MainTag" column. Something like the following could do it.

`re.sub(r"([\w\-]+)(?=:array<struct<BagId)", "_ids", maintag_schema)` - hopefully should rename that column to "_ids".
`` re.sub(r"(?<=,|<)([^,<]+)(?=:)", r"`\1`", maintag_schema) `` - hopefully should add `` ` `` around column/ field names which is needed for some field names.

```py
maintag_schema = df.schema["MainTag"].dataType.simpleString()
maintag_schema = re.sub(r"([\w\-]+)(?=:array<struct<BagId)", "_ids", maintag_schema)
maintag_schema = re.sub(r"(?<=,|<)([^,<]+)(?=:)", r"`\1`", maintag_schema)

df = df.withColumn("MainTag", F.col("MainTag").cast(maintag_schema))

df = df.selectExpr("inline(array(MainTag))")
df = df.selectExpr(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c != 'IDStruct'],
    "inline(IDStruct._ids)")
df = df.selectExpr(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c != 'LegCorr'],
    "inline(LegCorr)")
df = df.withColumn("IDArray", F.explode("IDArray"))

df.show()
# +-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
# |GroupId|    IDArray|     BagId|TravelerId|DelID|  SegID|
# +-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
# |  10C81|ABC-XYZ-123|42425fsdfs|   1234567|  SQH|PQR-UVW|
# |  10C81|ABC-XYZ-123|42425fsdfs|   1234567|  GFS|GHS-UVW|
# +-------+-----------+----------+----------+-----+-------+
```

Comment: In the below code can we somehow dynamically pass the hardcoded value 'ABC-XYZ-123' as it will vary for every record.
df = df.selectExpr(
    *[c for c in df.columns if c != 'IDStruct'],
    "inline(IDStruct.`ABC-XYZ-123`)")

Comment: Please look at the updated answer.